# Netbeans no reconoce la librería mysql-connector java

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, netbeans, h2

Estoy usando Netbeans 12.0, resulta que estoy intentando de conectar mi aplicación Java con una base de dato H2 Embedded, soy novato en este campo, lo que sucede es que en todos los tutoriales utilizan la librería java.sql.*.

Probé utilizando mysql-connector-java-8.0.22 este lo añado al proyecto correctamente, pero cuando quiero usar funciones de librería sql no aparecen ejemplo:
[image: Prueba1]

Como pueden ver intento de crear una Connection de java.sql pero no me deja importar java.sql.Connection.

Probe con diferentes versiones y nada. Espero si alguien es amable de explicarme si es necesario hacer algo "Extra" y no solo añadir el .jar al proyecto. Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer.

Edit: Lo que si eh logrado es conecta la base de dato en services de netbens

Edit 2:Eh probado en 2 computadoras distintas y tengo el mismo problema, así que la computadora no es ni el netbens, así que no sabría decir que lo ocasiona.

Comment: No soy experto en h2, pero si utilizas h2, ¿porqué no usar el connector de h2 en lugar del de mysql?

Comment: Eh añadido h2 al proyecto y pasa lo mismo, no puedo usar Java.sql

Comment: Lo máximo que pude lograr es que algunas cosas de mysql la dectecte y fue al usar la versión 5.0.1 si no me equivoco, en vez de la 8.0.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resulta que se trata de un ¿bug? Ya que al dar click en la lámpara cuando se arroja un error este no da la opción de importar Java.sql..., por eso yo asumí que netbeans no lo detectaba, la solución es muy simple si uno importa de forma manual:
import java.sql.*; automáticamente el código funcionará correctamente, dejo esta respuesta ya que lo probé en 3 computadoras distintas y en las 3 me dieron el mismo problema, así que talvez sea útil para alguien más.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta este punto tu ya agregaste el jar ya se ve como en la pantalla que se colocó en la consulta.

Una vez que tengas el jar del conector agregado y se vea en la parte izquierda
clic derecho sobre Libraries
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ir a properties

En la parte izquierda localizar Libraries

En la parte Izquierda debe aparecer la carpeta que agregaste con el jar, en mi caso es una carpeta que se llama Conector.

Seleccionarla y dar clic en el botón Move up hasta que quede en donde dice Modulepath.

Es todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]